# When will the SharePoint 2010 exams be available

Tags: exam, certification

Does anyone know when will the SharePoint 2010 exams be available?

Or if it is possible to take a Beta Exam?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to Microsoft Partner center this is the release schedule for the SharePoint 2010 exams and trainings.

**SharePoint Ignite** - **currently available**

Explore a **self-paced curriculum** including recorded presentations, demos, and hands-on-labs through Online Ignite — **coming in March 2010**.

**SharePoint 2010 Solution Designer**: **Available in Early 2010**

Future **SharePoint 2010 Certification Opportunities for IT Professionals**: **Coming in June 2010**
Certification Path for IT professionals
70-667 TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Configuring
70-668 PRO: SharePoint 2010, Administrator

Future **SharePoint 2010 Certification Opportunities for Developers**: **Coming in June 2010**
Certification Path for Developers
70-573 TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development
70-576 PRO: Designing and Developing Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Applications

I hope thís sheds some light on the exams. Note that all dates are preliminary.

/WW

Answer (score 4):

I found this recent update on SP 2010 Certifications at Joel's blog:

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=323

Answer (score 1):

July 12 according to the Published Date on the official MS Learning pages:

- TS 70-667: Microsoft SharePoint 2010,
  Configuring -
  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-667
- PRO 70-668: Microsoft SharePoint
  2010, Administrator -
  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-668
- TS 70-573: Microsoft SharePoint 2010,
  Application Development -
  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-573
- PRO 70-576: Designing and Developing
  Microsoft SharePoint 2010
  Applications -
  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-576

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly from a session at SharePoint Conference Las Vegas 2009, beta exams should be available near RTM release date, and full version few months after that. However this might have changed.