# When will the SharePoint 2013 exams be available

Tags: certification, exam

When will the SharePoint 2013 exams be available?

From the [2010 version of this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/when-will-the-sharepoint-2010-exams-be-available) it appeared to be about 6 months after release, should we expect a similar schedule?

Answer (score 7):

There are exams available **now** that you can take towards earning your [MCSE: SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-sharepoint-server.aspx) and MCSD:SharePoint Applications that will apply to MCSM:SharePoint.

MCSD: SharePoint details have not been published on the MS Learning site, but some details were mentioned in an MCSM Webinar in December 2012.

Note, that MCSE and MCSM level certifications have the version of the product removed, but the test will be based on SharePoint 2013 at first. Also, [MCSM: SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/MCSM-sharepoint.aspx) will require both MCSE:SharePoint and MCSD:SharePoint Appliactions certifications in addition to the MCSM rotation and exams.

### MCSE: SharePoint

MCSE: SharePoint requires:

1. [MCSA: Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-windows-server-MCSA.aspx) (available now)
2. [Exam 331: Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-331) (estimated Feb 2013)
3. [Exam 332: Advanced Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-332) (estimated Feb 2013)

Exam 331 and Exam 332 are expected to be released in February 2013, but MCSA: Windows Server 2012 is achievable right now.

### MCSA: Windows Server 2012

If you have earned MCITP SharePoint Administrator, a SharePoint 2010 certification, you can take the upgrade exam, [Exam 70-417: Upgrading Your Skills to MCSA Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-417), published September 2012.

If not, you can take the following exams, available now, to earn MCSA: Windows Server 2012:

1. [Exam 70-410: Installing and Configuring Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-410)
2. [Exam 70-411: Administering Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-411)
3. [Exam 70-412: Configuring Advanced Windows Server 2012 Services](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-412)

### MCSD: SharePoint Applications

MCSD: SharePoint Applications is expected to require:

1. Exam 70-488: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions
2. Exam 70-489: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions
3. [Exam 70-480: Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-480)
4. TBD: Possibly 70-486 or 70-487 from MCSD: Web Applications

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they are available right now, but I couln't find a valid schedule. It might be scheduled at the same time as the product release in Fabruray 2013? So far - these two exams are listed:

- [Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-331&Locale=en-us)
- [Advanced Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-332)

Answer (score 1):

There are always a round of Beta exams that are announced first that certain groups are given an invitation to take part in.  If I remember correctly those were available about the time of RTM and they work out the bugs shortly there after so I would expect 4-6 months after the release date.