# Am I running out of time to take the MCTS 70-667 Exam?

Tags: certification, 70-667

I am looking into taking the SharePoint 2010 Configuration 70-667 certification in a few months. Does anyone know since SharePoint 2013 is full throttle, if this is recommended or even if this certification exam will be around summer 2013? Is there a SharePoint 2013 certification similar to the 70-667 already out?

Answer (score 3):

the test/cert type/requirements can be changed at any given time. For test I think they go inline with microsoft support. As 2010 is heavily used and 2013 only just come out (not long ago), factoring in 2007 support is stopping.

general rule is when the next version of sharepoint comes out after 2013 is when 2010 will stop... including support. So its perfectly fine to take the test as its another 3+ years yet till the next version.

taking 2010 exam you can then topup to take 2013 exam :) , take a look at this:

http://jussionsharepoint.com/index.php/2012/09/14/the-definitive-guide-to-sharepoint-2013-certifications/

[When will the SharePoint 2013 exams be available](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41642/when-will-the-sharepoint-2013-exams-be-available)

on the ms website is states:

> - Retirement dates for these exams will be announced in 2013

so for a comparison sharepoint 2007 ended in:

> Exams expiring January 31, 2013:
>
> ◦Office SharePoint Server 2007 ◦70-542: TS: Microsoft Office
>   SharePoint Server 2007 – Application Development

Answer (score 2):

Do this one for administration:

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx

There is also an upgrade from 2010. Developer certificates are not available yet.